# Google Cloud Platform SQL instance won't accept **nodejs application** connections using custom user credentials

Tags: node.js, sql-server, google-cloud-platform, tedious

I have whitelisted my ip and  am able to connect to a google cloud platform sqlserver instance using the sqlcmd utility in my terminal.

`sqlcmd -S <ip-address> -U <username> -P<password>`

However, when I try this same attempt from my node application on the same machine, I am unable to connect:

my configuration:

```
const sql = require('mssql')

const dconfig = {
  server: 'X.X.X.X',
  authentication: {
    type: 'default',
    options: {
      userName: '<username>',
      password: '<password>'
    }
  },
  database: 'logs',
  options: {
    appname: 'ms-inx-notify-prod'
  }
}

const cpool = new sql.ConnectionPool(dconfig).connect().catch((err) => { console.log(err) })
```

This configuration option works when I connect to a local sqlserver instance that I have installed, but when I changed some parameters to point to the GCP database, it doesn't connect successfully.

This is the error:

> { ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'username'.
>          at ConnectionError (/home/ziggyjosh16/Projects/Node/node_modules/tedious/lib/errors.js:13:12)
>          at Parser.tokenStreamParser.on.token (/home/ziggyjosh16/Projects/Node/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:818:51)
>          at Parser.emit (events.js:193:13)
>          at Parser.parser.on.token (/home/ziggyjosh16/Projects/Node/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/token-stream-parser.js:33:14)
>          at Parser.emit (events.js:193:13)
>          at addChunk (/home/ziggyjosh16/Projects/Node/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:297:12)
>          at readableAddChunk (/home/ziggyjosh16/Projects/Node/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:279:11)
>          at Parser.Readable.push (/home/ziggyjosh16/Projects/Node/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:240:10)
>          at Parser.Transform.push (/home/ziggyjosh16/Projects/Node/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:139:32)
>          at doneParsing (/home/ziggyjosh16/Projects/Node/node_modules/tedious/lib/token/stream-parser.js:114:14)
>        message: "Login failed for user 'username'.",
>        code: 'ELOGIN' },
>     name: 'ConnectionError' }

(EDIT): I also discovered that if you use the MSSQL default user account for connecting (sqlserver) the above code works successfully. I think this is an issue with the google account platform roles. Is there an option or a setting in GCP which will allow me to connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the issue: you need to do an ALTER ROLE to give the new user a role. I had reproduced your error when I created a new user without doing that step, but now I can create new users and connect with them fine. I gave the new user the built-in `db_ddladmin` role, so it's able to create a table.

Here's a Python script that creates a new user for SQL Server authentication and then connects as that user: https://gist.github.com/dmahugh/ae0b829f85c3bbd9ba332712b305bf6b

I'm not familiar with Tedious, but it looks like you pass SQL commands to it with `connection.execSQL()`, so you should be able to do something like the example in that gist, and then you can connect as the new user in the same way that you connect as the sqlserver default admin account.

Comment: Is this solution applicable to a Google Cloud Platform SQL Server instance? I initially tried this per this document: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/users

I turned out that the roles that the documentation provide did not exist for my SQLserver instance.

Comment: I should also add that the user I created is able to connect using `sqlcmd`. I'm not aware of any permission that blacklists a nodejs app connection but allows connection through sqlcmd. I will try to ALTER ROLE to  the `db_ddladmin`

Comment: Looks like by default the `sqlserver` user does not have the permissions to alter roles:

```ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [ms-inx-notify]
2> go
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Server a-508910053816-, Line 1
Cannot alter the role 'db_ddladmin', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with mssql, but I THOUGHT the config didn't use the `authentication` tag, but instead directly uses the `user` and `password` tags?

Looking at the mssql docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#general-same-for-all-drivers

Comment: I am using the Tedious driver for my database connections, it's one of the options you can use for mssql library. http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html

Comment: are you familiar with GCP SQL? It appears there's nothing wrong with the code: I was able to connect to the database using the credential for the default user `sqlserver`. It seems any of the other users that I create cannot authenticate through my node application. 

This is strange since the sqlcmd allows my to connect with my created users. So maybe there is something missing between the sqlserver user and my created users. The GCP doesn't make SQL permissions immediately viewable in the console.

Comment: Interesting, so the code you have works as long as you're using the sqlserver creds? Let me ping a colleague of mine that knows SQL Server more than I do. He might have some ideas.

Comment: My colleague managed to reproduce it internally here. Stay tuned, we're going to spin up a little group to see if we can figure out what's going on.

Comment: Gabe, were you able to figure out anything new?

Comment: I roped in Doug to chime in and help figure it out. He knows way more about SQL Server than I do.

Comment: Thanks Gabe, In the meantime I think I will be moving towards a working `MySQL` instance.

Comment: *nod* Or use pyodbc maybe instead of mssql? I know Doug has scripts that use that library and it's a known quantity. If MySQL works for you though, it IS a better-known setup since it's been around much longer.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the delay - just catching up after the holidays. Josh, if I'm understanding correctly, you weren't able to ALTER ROLE [db_ddladmin] from your NodeJS app, correct? I *am* able to do that via pyodbc as shown in that sample I linked to in the answer above. And you're doing this as the sqlserver user, which is the same as me. Let me know if that's where we're at - we may want to file a bug on this if that's what's happening.

Comment: Sorry Doug missed this comment. I didn't use the python script. I simply tried executing the command `ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [ms-inx-notify]` A using admin in the sql console for the existing user. Assuming that does work, does the documentation need to be updated to include an extra step or is this maybe an fix for gcp when creating new users?